# DAX : Calculated table with FILTER using a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table Tb01 containing the orders.
I would like to create a second table that would contain all orders of a specific customer, selected by the user in a slicer.

I tried to create a new table as :

```
tb02 = FILTER(Tb01;Tb01[Customer] = SELECTEDVALUE(Tb01[Customer])
```

It didn't work (the table was empty), so I tried the next idea :

```
tb02 = VAR currentCust = SELECTEDVALUE(Tb01[Customer])
RETURN FILTER(tb01; tb01[Customer] = currentCust)
```

because I read that the context was evaluated first and then the execution of the second command. I got a table but with all my clients.
So it didn't work

How can I do this ?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculated tables cannot be responsive to slicers since they are only computed once each time the data model is loaded.

It is possible to create dynamically calculated tables *within a measure* but you can't have dynamic tables in your data model.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I understand. I will try to create a measure in this case